# What is the best alternative with goto Statement

Tags: c#

I'm cleaning up a program which should be able to replace all the **goto statements** with a more readable alternative. I encountered this kind of problem inside my loop. Here is the code.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
labelReturn:
    //Some Code

    for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
    {
        y = i * x + j
        if (y == 5)
        {
            i++;
            goto labelReturn;
        }
    }
    //If Statement{}
    //Some Code
}
```

if I replace `i++;` `goto labelReturn;` with break. It just break the current for loop and it will execute the next statement of "If". Is there a way that i can break the loop and continue the iteration without executing the next codes/statements.

Comment: Can you give a more realistic example of the condition you're testing in the innermost `if` statement? I strongly suspect that the answer is to refactor the inner loop into a separate method, but we can't really tell.

Comment: You can refactor the implementation in the `labelReturn:` into another method `LabelReturn(..)`.

Comment: I was just thinking the same thing. The inner loop will never get `j` to 6, and that's just one oddity.

Comment: Are you aware that that code will never terminate? You´re allways returning to `labelReturn`, execute the inner loop five times and return again. So although `i` will increase you never check it´s value anywhere.

Comment: Your code would enter an infinite loop because, after executing the goto statement, it would start the second `for` loop again with `i` having the exact same value as the last time. So the code is bogus. Use `continue` to go up and start the *next iteration* of the closest parent loop. But that wouldn't work here if you really want an endless loop.

Comment: @ZoharPeled    its not infinite because of i++ before goto

Comment: It *is* infinite, as you never *check* the value of `i` (the `i < 100` within your for-loop is called only on the very first iteration).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply create some flag that indicates of the condition in the *inner* loop was  met and if so, skip the code after that inner loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    bool found = false;
    //Some Code

    for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
    {
        y = i * x + j
        if (y == 5)
        {
            i++;
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(found) // do something

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply call `continue` after your inner loop calls `break`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    //Some Code

    for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
    {
        y = i * x + j
        if (y == 5)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    if (y == 5)
        continue;
    //If Statement{}
    //Some Code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    //Some Code
    int j;
    for (j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
         // if (something) break;
    }
    if( j < 5) // do something

}
```